# How to Import multiple ant files in build gradle and run from azure Devops pipeline

Tags: gradle, azure-devops, ant, build.gradle

I have multiple ant files in project and trying to run using build.gradle file in below way

build.gradle

```
ant.importBuild('test\abc.xml') { antTargetName ->
   'a-' + antTargetName
}

ant.importBuild('test\def.xml') { antTargetName ->
   'b-' + antTargetName
}
```

Both xml file are having same target name(run)

I am using azure Devops task and it is running fine for first one a-run but when I call second task (b-run) after first task successful it fails with task b-run not found in root project "BC". Some candidates are: 'a-run'

azure Devops task:

```
- task: Gradle@3
  inputs:
    gradleWrapperFiles: '$(sourceDir)/BC/gradlew'
    workdingDirectory: '$(sourceDir)/BC'
    tasks: a-run

- task: Gradle@3
  inputs:
    gradleWrapperFiles: '$(sourceDir)/BC/gradlew'
    workdingDirectory: '$(sourceDir)/BC'
    tasks: b-run


Project structure
BC->
   test\abc.xml
   test\cde.xml
   gradle
   gradlew
   gradlew.bat
   gradle.properties
   source
   build.gradle
```

What could be the issue?